Ollama - SpringAi Image Description(Detection) Problem
I have this code in spring boot and the background LLM is Ollama:
package sample.rag.vector;
import org.springframework.ai.chat.client.ChatClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
public class ImageDetection {

    private final ChatClient chatClient;
    @Value("classpath:/images/sh.jpg")
    Resource sampleImage;

    public ImageDetection(ChatClient.Builder builder) {
        this.chatClient = builder.build();
    }

    @GetMapping("/imgtotxt")
    public String image() throws IOException {
        return chatClient.prompt()
                .user(u -> u
                        .text("what you see in the following image?")
                        .media(MimeTypeUtils.IMAGE_JPEG,sampleImage)
                )
                .call()
                .content();
    }
}

And this run with OpenAI(ChatGPT) but in Ollama it return bellow message when I call imgtotxt REST Api.
Message: I don't see any image. You provided a text-based representation of an image, but I don't have the capability to visually access images. If you'd like to describe the image to me, I'll do my best to help you understand it. Alternatively, if you can share a link or upload the image directly, I may be able to assist you further.
Is there any problem in code or this is basically Ollama Problem?

spring.ai.ollama.chat.model=llama3.2:3b / java: 21
/ Spring 3.3.4
